# PHP fetch array in RainTPL

Tags: php, smarty

i want to use array and fetch that with rainTpl, i can assign array for it but i cant fetch

**PHP:**

```
$portalTopics   =array(
array('id' => 4,
        'subject' => 1111111,
        'description' => vvvvvvvvvvvvv,
        'date_time' => '2013-05-26',
        'posted_by' => 1,
        'tags' => '',
        'category' => 1,
        't_status' => 1,
        'post_type' => 1,
        'can_comment' => 1,
        'from_dateTime' =>' 0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'to_dateTime' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'portal' => 0,
        'thumb_image' => 'eNortjKwUlKyBlwwB0UBlw',
        'order_display' => 9
      ),
array('id' => 5,
        'subject' => 22222222222,
        'description' => fffffffffffff,
        'date_time' => '2013-05-26',
        'posted_by' => 1,
        'tags' => '',
        'category' => 1,
        't_status' => 1,
        'post_type' => 1,
        'can_comment' => 1,
        'from_dateTime' =>' 0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'to_dateTime' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'portal' => 0,
        'thumb_image' => 'eNortjKwUlKyBlwwB0UBlw',
        'order_display' => 9
      )          
);

    $tpl->assign( $portalSettings );
    $tpl->assign( 'portalTopics',$portalTopics );
    echo $tpl->draw( 'main');
```

this below code is my `main.html` file for fetch `portalTopics` array

**RainTPL:**

```
<div> 
    <ul>
        {loop="portalTopics"}
            <li>{$key} = {$value}</li>
        {/loop}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**RESULT :**

```
0 = Array
1 = Array
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a 2D array, but you do only loop the outer one. If you want to display the key value pairs from the 2nd level, you have to put another loop in your loop (nested loop) that accesses the key value pairs from your inner arrays.

```
<div> 
    <ul>
        {loop="portalTopics"}
            {loop="value"}
                <li>{$key} = {$value}</li>
            {/loop}
        {/loop}
    </ul>
</div>
```